# Identify this packaging

Tags: packages, enclosure, waterproof, underwater

I've seen this packaging used by many companies, specifically in mobile equipment, automotive ECU's, marine, and other harsh environment applications.  I doubt all these manufactures are making the packaging for themselves, so it must be some sort of standard format that I can purchase.

To describe the packaging, I would call it a rectangular box that's a solid plastic housing on 5 sides but one, that normally has a single PCB counterpart that slides down in and has a 'cap' on one side of the PCB.  Sliding the PCB into the until the cap 'clicks' into place gives it a watertight seal.  The cap usually has 1 or 2 Deutsch style or other automotive connector.  Additionally the main housing usually has 2 tabs off it for an M8 / 1/4" bolt to secure it to a flat surface.

Some examples:

[image]
[image]

Any info on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any manufacturer markings internally?

Comment: I don't have one of these on hand right now.  I used to use products in this packaging several years ago.  If I have to, I'm just going to order something to get it on hand and take it apart.

Comment: Why do you think they don't do it for themselves? Have you seen twice the same package? I didn't. It's very difficult to find these enclosures and stuffs and when you find them it's prohibitively expensive.

Comment: I've held some these packages in my hand from different and know for certain they are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Deutsch themselves makes the whole enclosure:

https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/connectors/automotive-connectors/intersection/deutsch-pcb-enclosures-and-headers.html

Thanks for playing